# Não encontra diretório do arquivo

Tags: java, android

Tenho um método que faz parte de uma classe para capturar a assinatura do cliente.

Mas ele esta dando problemas na hora de abrir o `FileOutputStream`, aparece `"No such file or directory"`

segue o metodo:

```
/**
 * 
 * @param MEDIA_DIRECTORY ex: /storage/emulated/0/appname/assinaturas-consultas/
 * @param STOREDPATH ex: /storage/emulated/0/appname/assinaturas-consultas/teste.png
 * @return
 */
public boolean save(String MEDIA_DIRECTORY, String STOREDPATH) {
    view.setDrawingCacheEnabled(true);
    if (bitmap == null)
        bitmap = Bitmap.createBitmap(640, 480, Bitmap.Config.RGB_565);

    Canvas canvas = new Canvas(bitmap);
    view.draw(canvas);
    try {
        File storageDir = new File(MEDIA_DIRECTORY);
        if (!storageDir.exists())
            storageDir.mkdirs();

        FileOutputStream out = new FileOutputStream(STOREDPATH); //Erro acontece aqui.
        view.draw(canvas);
        bitmap.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.PNG, 90, out);

        out.flush();
        out.close();
        return true;
    } catch (Exception e) {
        Log.e("log_tag", e.toString());
    }
    return false;
}
```

eu também já coloquei essas duas linhas no `Manifest`:

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
```

Answer (score 0):

Isto acontece pois o arquivo correspondente ao STOREDPATH não existe. Você precisa criar o arquivo antes de usa-ló no FileOutputStream.

Ficaria assim:

```
File storedFile = new File(STOREDPATH);
if (!storedFile.exists())
  storedFile.createNewFile();

FileOutputStream out = new FileOutputStream(storedFile); //Erro acontece aqui.
```